# Увеличение раздела HDD в Debian [Закрыт]

Tags: debian, linux

Доброго времени форумчане.
Возникла такая необходимость как увеличить корневой раздел (ext3). Возможно ли такое в Linux, например с помощью PartitionMagic или им подобным, Debian после этой операции переустанавливать не придется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Да, возможно увеличить корневой раздел.
2. Если был использован LVM - можно увеличить на лету. Если стандартная схема разметки - боюсь, что со стандартными средствами только через удаление раздела.
3. Всегда можно воспользоваться PM :-) или любым другим "серьезным" разбивальщиком дисков.

Comment: Т.е. я просто увеличиваю размер раздела с помощью, например PM, и конфиги ни какие править не нужно будет (fstab, lilo.conf)?

Comment: Конфиги нужно править в случае, если Вы добавите/удалите разделы, т.е. съедет нумерация.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно любой раздел можна увеличить если между тем разделом который надо увеличить и тем которой идет после него есть свободное дисковое пространство, но так как это будет только в том случае если так **специально разметили**
Возможна стоит подумать о других вариатах
 1. Если /opt используестя по своему премому назначению перенести его куда-нибудь и сделать symlink /opt на тот *старый*перенесенный opt.
 2. смонтировать /tmp в оперативку
 3. пересобрать некоторые программы таки образом что-бы они находилсь не в корне.
 4. Перенесьте часть /var куда нибудь (опять же все тот же симлинк нам здесь пригодится)

---

---

Но все таки лучше не делать 4 пункт без необходимости